`upgradeAndCall()` Reverting
I have a factory contract which deploys an upgradable token and I also want it to be able to upgrade it. It works fine when I callupgradeAndCall() with an empty data but when I try pass in an encoded version of my param that is expected in my initialize() function it reverts.
Here is what I mean
My upgrade function
function upgradeSemiNativeToken(address _proxyAdmin, address _myFunnyAddress) external {
    address newContractImpl = _create3(
        type(MyContract).creationCode,
        0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003039
    ); //12345

    if (newContractImpl == address(0)) revert DeploymentFailed();

  
    encodedData = abi.encodeWithSignature('initialize(address)', _myFunnyAddress);

    // WORKS FINE
    // ProxyAdmin(_proxyAdmin).upgradeAndCall(s_contractProxy, newContractImpl, "");

    // REVERTS
    ProxyAdmin(_proxyAdmin).upgradeAndCall(s_contractProxy, newContractImpl, encodedData);

}

Anyone see what I might be doing wrong here?
For full context here is my v2 contract that I am trying to upgrade to. It's more or less the same as v1 leaving my initialize() function for full context
    function initialize(address _myFunnyAddress) public initializer {
        __ERC20_init('My lame token', 'TOKEN2');
        __ERC20Burnable_init();
        s_myFunnyAddresss = _myFunnyAddress
    }

Thanks for the help!

Could you share the upgradeAndCall function with us?

its defined here
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/05f218fb6617932e56bf5388c3b389c3028a7b73/contracts/proxy/transparent/ProxyAdmin.sol#L38

Turns out this was working fine all along it was just a misunderstanding on my end regarding upgradables. Calling initialize() again was blocked due to modifier initializer modifier just doing its job. I do not need to run initialize() again as the state of my proxy remains the same. i.e. the params that are passed in my initialize() function do not need to be passed in again. Thanks!
